# ECMAScriptのDateコンストラクタ引数にローカル時刻を指定したときのタイムゾーンオフセットについて

Tags: javascript

例えばタイムゾーンがアメリカ合衆国の環境でサマータイム終了日のDateオブジェクトを以下のように生成した時

```
new Date(2018, 10, 4, 1, 30) // 2018年11月4日 午前01:30
```

そのオブジェクトのUTC時刻は夏時間終了前となるか、夏時間終了後となるか、もしくは未定義か、知りたいです。

[ECMAScript® 2019 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-local-time-zone-adjustment) によると

> When tlocal represents local time repeating multiple times at a
>   negative time zone transition (e.g. when the daylight saving time ends
>   or the time zone adjustment is decreased due to a time zone rule
>   change) or skipped local time at a positive time zone transitions
>   (e.g. when the daylight saving time starts or the time zone adjustment
>   is increased due to a time zone rule change), tlocal must be
>   interpreted with the time zone adjustment before the transition.

とありますが、上記の例（2018年11月4日 午前01:30）は常に夏時間終了前の時刻になる、という解釈で合っているでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

はい、その場合は常に夏時間終了前の時刻になります。

引用された部分の最後に “tlocal must be interpreted with the time zone adjustment before the transition.” とあり、the time zone adjustment before the transitionとは変化が発生する前（夏時間が終了する前）のオフセットを指していると考えられます。

また、その直後のNOTEに夏時間終了時の具体例が書かれています。

> 1:30 AM on November 5, 2017 in America/New_York is repeated twice (fall backward), but it must be interpreted as 1:30 AM UTC-04 instead of 1:30 AM UTC-05.

America/New_York タイムゾーンにおいては夏時間があり、夏時間時はUTC-04, 夏時間終了後はUTC-05となります。このNOTEによると、2017年11月5日のAM 01:30という時刻は夏時間終了に伴って2回発生しますが、UTC-04（夏時間終了前）で解釈されなければならない (must) とされています。